# Solution of differential equation $\sin(y)\space dx=\cos(y)\space dy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find integrating factor in
> $$\sin (y) \space dx=\cos(y) \space dy$$ and also finding solution of that equation.

What I try:$$\sin(y)\space dx=\cos(y) \space dy$$

$$\int \frac{\cos y}{\sin y}\space dy=\int dx$$

$$\ln(\sin y)=x+C$$

But I did not understand how can I find the Integrating factor here. Help me please.

Comment: $\ln (|\sin y|)$ ,  right?

Comment: To find $C$ shouldn't you know hot $y$ relates with $x$. At least at one point i.e. know something like $y(x_0)$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you really mean "integrating factor"? That's something you use when you can't do the integration without it, but you've done the integration without using one.

Comment: @alphaomega, Integrating **factor** isn't the same thing as constant of integration.

Comment: @MarcoCiafa You are right. But given the structure of the question, I assumed $C$  was the issue.

Comment: If you really want something, you could say the integrating factor is **1**.

Answer (score 2):

A differential equation of the form $ M(x,y)\,dx + N(x,y)\,dy = 0 $ is said to be exact if
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} M(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} N(x,y)$$

This is not you case. However, sometimes you can find a function $\mu(x,y)$ called integrating factor by which you can multiply your equation in order to make it exact. That means that
$$ \mu(x,y)M(x,y)\,dx + \mu(x,y)N(x,y)\,dy = 0 $$
is exact.

If, you can't find the integrating factor just with the definition and your thoguhts, you can appeal to a more mecahnical device. You can deduce some [formulas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecuaci%C3%B3n_diferencial_exacta#Factor_integrante_s%C3%B3lo_en_funci%C3%B3n_de_x.) (it's in Spanish, but you can see them anyways) for $\mu$ in the special cases where it has the form $\mu(x)$, $\mu(y)$, $\mu(x+y)$ or $\mu(xy)$.

**Obs. 1:** The integrand in the formulas depending only on $x$ , $y$, $x+y$, $xy$, respectively, is a *necesary and sufficient condition* for the integrating factor to exist.

After trying each one of them, you will realise that the second one will work (althought you will get $C\,|\sin(y)|^{-1}$, for any $C\in\mathbb{R}$). This result should inspire you into just taking $\sin(y)^{-1}$ which is nicer and **also works**.

**Obs. 2:** The integrating factor is not unique.

You can check that $ 1\,dx - \cot(y)\,dy = 0 $ is exact.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The question is: "How can I find the integrating factor?"

Comment: It says how to find the integrating factor in the OP's example. He just has to use the second formula on the link. Apparently my answer is not clear, I will edit it.